# Wireless Internet stops working until reconnect to WiFi Router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Sometimes, like once per 20 minutes, internet suddenly stops working on my Mac. If I turn AirPort off and then on, it becomes working again.

With the same frequency, internet stops working on my iPod touch. If I turn wi-fi off and then on (or airplane mode on and then off) it becomes working again too.

I think it has something to do with my router preferences. But I have no idea where to look, please give me a clue!

---

My router is Asus GT-32, Firmware Version: 2.0.0.5

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons. It would help if you posted the model of your router.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion, I've added this information

Answer (score 1):

It might be the setting of the router concerning the DHCP lease : The amount of time that the DHCP server grants to the DHCP client permission to use a particular IP address. In this case it would make more sense to change it to not expire or extend the lease period.

If the lease expires, there's still a good chance that the router will assign you the same IP again. The lease expiration itself may disconnect your device, depending on the router's behavior and/or settings.

So go into your router's settings screen and check DHCP lease time.

There are newer firmware versions for the RT-G32 available from [here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=RT-G32&p=11&s=2). It might be worthwhile to upgrade (very carefully). Pay attention to the version you download, as it seems that there exists also an RT-G32 Rev.B1, which is probably not your router.

Comment: thank you! Lease time: 86400 http://cl.ly/2t241z3d3n0O1i3u3q2W

Comment: Well that should be enough actually.

Comment: 1 day = 86400 seconds. Are the troublesome devices connected longer than that ?

Comment: I also added some firmware info to my answer.

Comment: I don't know why - it uploads the new firmware, but the version stays the same (even after the reboot)

Comment: You should be using the utility that can be downloaded from the same place.